# Expected value of sum of first k out of N weighted Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: pr.probability

I am investigating the following problem.

Consider N Normal variables with same mean, but difefrent variances. What is the PDF of the linear combination of the largest K random variables  being greater than a given threhold? I aprreciate if anyone give pointers.

Thanks

kamesh

Comment: The question is unclear to me: What do you mean by "being greater than ..."? Is something conditioned on being greater than the threshold? If yes, what? The $K$ random variables or their mean? 

Answer (score 1):

This is studied exhaustively in [this paper.](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~wiens/home%20page/pubs/orderstats.pdf) (On the exact distribution of the sum of the largest n − k out of n normal random variables with differing mean values
DOUGLAS P. WIENS*†, NORMAN C. BEAULIEU‡ and PAVEL LOSKOT‡)

Comment: It's not quite the same problem.  The OP asked about equal means but different variances, and the linked paper deals with equal variances and different means.

Comment: True, my oversight, but I am quite sure that the methods work fine in the different setting.